# how to pass variable sized parameter on callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Is there a flexible and generic way on how to pass variable sized parameter on callback in Javascript?

```
var myCallback = function (param1, param2){
    ...
};
var myOtherCallback = function (param1, param2, param3){
    ...
};

var func = function(callback, callbackParams){
    // how can I put the values on callbackParams as the actual callback parameters down here?
    callback( /* callbackParams */ );
};

func(myCallback, [myparam1, myparam2]);
func(myOtherCallback, [newparam1, newparam2, newparam3]);
```

Comment: If you're going to call the callback with your own arguments then why use a callback at all?

Comment: it's much more complicated on my actual code, the use of that callback is necessary, I just simplify it here.

Comment: You can use `Funtion.prototype.apply` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for...

```
var myCallback = function (param1, param2){
    console.log("myCallback", param1, param2)
};
var myOtherCallback = function (param1, param2, param3){
    console.log("myCallback", param1, param2, param3)
};

var func = function(callback){
    var additionalParams = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    callback.apply(this, additionalParams);
};

func(myCallback, "myparam1", "myparam2");
func(myOtherCallback, "newparam1", "newparam2", "newparam3");
```

although for a more modern approach, Kuu Aku's answer might be better

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [spread operator](https://rainsoft.io/how-three-dots-changed-javascript/) in your function. 
That being said, I don't see any use for callback in your example. I assumed that your purposely simplified your problem to explain it to us.

```
var myCallback = function (param1, param2){
    ...
};
var myOtherCallback = function (param1, param2, param3){
    ...
};

var func = function(callback, callbackParams){
    // how can I put the values on callbackParams as the actual callback parameters down here?
    callback(...callbackParams);
};

func(myCallback, [myparam1, myparam2]);
func(myOtherCallback, [newparam1, newparam2, newparam3]);
```